# How can I render a child component completely replacing the parent component in React?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

I am working with React and I need to understand how can I render a component that replace its parent component.
For example the screenshot 1.
For now the way I do is when clicking on a FARM button it goes into a new page with the data related to that particular farm.
Now I need to have all the data for each farm in this main page and when the button is clicked the parent component pass the data only related to the  chosen farm and redirect me to the specific page for that farm (screenshot 2).
How can I make so when the button is clicked the parent component disappear and the component in the screenshot 2 takes the place with the data passed from the parent?